# Getting Servlet request object in listener?

Tags: spring, httprequest

How can i get the `HttpServletRequest` object in my `org.springframewrok.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` which i configured in `web.xml`.

I am using `Spring 3.0` with `Struts2`.

I know I can get the `ServletContext` by implementing `ServletContextListener`, but I need the `request` object inside the listener.

Comment: What kind of listener have you configured in web.xml?

Comment: org.springframewrok.web.context.request.RequestContextListener

Comment: Please consider reading the documentation of the class you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`RequestContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) which is the parameter to `requestDestroyed` and `requestInitialized` methods in your [`RequestContextListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html).